# How do I create a custom ResponseType in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm interested in extending Scrapy in my project by adding a custom ResponseType.  For now, I want to add a PDF type that will use PDFMiner to return the plain text and structure of the document (including links).  I may want to add other document types later.

It looks like the mapping from mime types to response classes happens in [scrapy.responsetypes](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/responsetypes.py) -- specifically the `CLASSES` dictionary in `ResponseTypes`.  However, it's not clear if/how that is intended to be overridden with custom response classes.  The `responsetypes` variable at the end of that file gets referenced directly in a few other places, and I don't see any reference to this class in the Scrapy project settings.  Additionally, I wasn't able to find anything about how to do this in the Scrapy documentation.

I could of course fork Scrapy and use my own version with custom classes defined, but that would introduce a maintenance headache.

What's the best way to define custom response types in Scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that. Scrapy expects you to be satisfied with its default response types.
You *could* replace the download handlers and middlewares which use this class, but that would probably be too much work...

The simplest way to get a similar result would probably be to just add an additional downloader middleware which will:

- be called after all the other (relevant) downloader middlewares
- check the `Content-Type` header of the scrapy-created response
- if needed, replace the response with your custom one

This does do additional work (creates an additional response object after the normal processing is done), but it's much simpler to implement than the alternative.